# How to write a synchronous AJAX in plain JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to do an AJAX call in a loop with below code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  ajax_DatabaseAccessor.query("CheckInt", i, loadQuery);
  function loadQuery(data) {
    alert(DWRUtil.toDescriptiveString(data, 2));
  }
}
```

I debugged the code, the log were wrote five times then ajax were executed and the passing parameter i is 4. I doubt the reason is this is an asynchronous call. Then how to modify the code to make it synchronous? I know jquery can do it with setting async, but how to write it in plain javascript without jquery? Thx.

Comment: so, you want synchronous AJAX? ... or, in other words ... JAX - since the first A in AJAX === Asynchronous  - it's in the name!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to use the for loop construct with asynchronous code, but have it behave like synchronous code (which is assumed by a for loop) these days is to use `async/await` syntax.

Rewrite your `ajax_DatabaseAccessor.query` to return a promise (for example, you can use `fetch` if you are doing an HTTP request) and to be an `async` function. For example, let's say it was defined like this:

```
let ajax_DatabaseAccessor = {}
ajax_DatabaseAccessor.query = async (idk, someIdea, someSelector) => {
    let response = await fetch("some_resource/"+idk+"/+"someIdea)
    let data = await response.json();
    return someSelector(data)
}
```

Now that your code is `awaitable` you can use it from your for loop, so we get something like:

```
for(var i = 0 ;i<5;i++){
  let myDescriptiveString = await ajax_DatabaseAccessor.query("CheckInt", i,  (data)=>DWRUtil.toDescriptiveString(data, 2));  
}
```

The point is the answer to your question, if understood or interpreted most charitably, is to look into `fetch`, `async/await`, due to its ability to play nicely with for loops. You may also sometimes come across situations where you want to write an `awaitable` function -- in which case it will help to know how to create a `Promise` and knowing that a promise is something you can `await` on will help as well.